# Is it possible to center a SVG pattern image fill without using JavaScript?

Tags: svg, css-position

I have the following SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="480" height="1080" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 480 1080" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

     <defs>
  <pattern id="wpi" width="100%" height="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <image width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="h_img.jpg" x="0" y="0"/>
  </pattern>
 </defs>
 <rect class="wallpaper" width="100%" height="250" fill="url(#wpi)"/>
</svg>
```

The h_img jpg might vary on time, loading different images, so I can't be aware of its size in advance, yet I know that, most of the time, its height value is greater than its width but I need to apply it to a rect element that has a smaller height compared to its own width and this is for sure (despite I'm using a relative 100% value for that one). **I need the pattern to fill that rect with the image maintaining its aspect ratio and the height being crop (or hide overflow) centered.** I know I can use JavaScript to calculate the image relative width, resize the height accordingly to maintain the aspect ratio and calculate the offset needed to provide the centering (and I did) but... **Do you know maybe is there a way to do what I need simply using the right parameters on the SVG element and no JavaScript?**

I tried with:

```
<pattern id="wpi" width="100%" height="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <image width="1" height="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" xlink:href="h_img.jpg" x="0" y="0"/>
</pattern>
```

But that doesn't get me the desired effect I need...
Thanks for your help

**SOLVED EDIT:**

Thanks to @ccprog for his suggestion took me on the right direction, I managed to find a way to solve like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="480" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 480 1080" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
 <defs>
  <pattern id="wpi" width="1" height="1">
   <image width="100%" height="250" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="h_img.jpg"/>
  </pattern>
 </defs>
 <rect class="wallpaper" width="100%" height="250" fill="url(#wpi)"/>
</svg>
```

Notice: you need to **set for the `<image>` just the same `height` and `width` values used for the pattern image container** area (= that means the size of the element on which the pattern is going to be applied, in this case it's a `<rect>`).

As final words I'll say there are at least a couple of reasons for I wanted the image to stay applied within a pattern:

- one is that, in this way, I can be able to use javascript code to shift the centering of the image by `y` and `x` attributes values while letting the rectangle stay in its position;
- and another reason is I could change the rectangle fill to a solid color easily if I need doing it.

Comment: Does your solution "repeats" the pattern while keeping it centered? I'm looking for a way of doing that. I mean, my pattern is smaller than my container. I want it on center, and repeated on both sides. And this is on a responsive container, so that adjustment needs to be dynamic and keep it centered even when container resizes. It's doable with JS, but I would like to use SVG only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display an image once in a rectangular area, you do not need a pattern. Patterns are for repeating content more than once.

The attribute you were searching for is `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`. See the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute).

```
<svg width="480" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 480 1080"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <image class="wallpaper" width="100%" height="250"
          preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="h_img.jpg"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, you drove me to the right direction with your suggestion and half addressed the problem solution so I'll not only up-vote but also accept yours as the answer. Thanks again and sorry for the delay...

Comment: P.S. I also edited my question with the final solution I worked out starting from your suggestion and the reasons why I wanted to keep using an image pattern for it :-)